# File not found exception, access is denied

Tags: windows

I'm trying to run a program in windows 7 environment. It is giving me this error,

Exception unloading sessions to persistent storage
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\dir...

How do i give permissions in windows 7 for the directory dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows prevents applications from writing to the "Program Files" directory as a matter of policy. Choose a different location to store your files.

If this error is being generated by the Java framework itself, upgrade it.

Comment: this is actually an installed program (a BPM tool) that is trying to access those files. Even in such a case, should i reinstall it in a directory like D: to give full permissions to it?

Comment: @elle, an answer for an installed application that you don't have control over is outside the scope of this site. I really don't have an answer for that.